# LINQ Queries with dynamic OrderBy on property and complex object

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, lambda

With the code below, I don't have any problem to sort on `FirstName` and `LastName` 
but I'd like be able to sort on `Name` and `Code` too. Is there a solution to sort on a property and this property is a "complex object" not a primitive ?

Thanks,

My objects :

```
public class Person
{
    public Language Language { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I have this piece of code to sort :

```
var type = typeof(T);
var property = type.GetProperty("OrderBy");
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
MethodCallExpression resultExp = 
    Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), 
    "OrderBy",
    new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType }, 
    source.Expression, 
    Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
```

Comment: There are no subclasses in your code. Name and code are properties of a property of your Person class.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares lets me rephrase ... And it's not all the time a "Language" object but can be another type.

Comment: @Kris-I: Please edit the title of the question then - I read it looking for subclasses too.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a solution to sort on a property and this property is a "complex object" not a primitive ?

Sure - you'd have to basically create an expression tree equivalent to:

```
data.OrderBy(p => p.Language.Name)
```

That's basically two property access expressions, where the "source" of one of them is the "result" of another. So you'd need to take your property string (e.g. "Language.Name"), split it up into sections, then iterate over the individual bits, keeping a current expression as the target. Something like:

```
Expression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
Expression target = parameter;
foreach (string property in propertyParts)
{
    target = Expression.Property(target, property);
}
var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(target, parameter);
```

Comment: You can replace the loop with a simple fold: `target = propertyParts.Aggregate(target, Expression.Property);`.

Also, I think you forgot to declare and assign `parameter`.

Comment: @ThomSmith: Fixed the declaration of parameter, but personally I'd find the `foreach` loop easier to understand than an `Aggregate` call. Of all the LINQ operators, I find `Aggregate` one of the least simple to use. I understand the principles - I just always find I have to think harder when using that than others. Obviously if you come from a functional background that's likely to help...

Comment: YMMV, of course. `Aggregate` does sometimes bug me, probably because Microsoft decided to arbitrarily rename all of the standard functional operators for LINQ, and binary `fold` and unary `reduce` got shoehorned in together.

Comment: @ThomSmith: I wouldn't say it was *arbitrary*. I'd say it was to give them names which would be more meaningful to the *majority* of users. I'm sure if they were *only* trying to cater to an existing functional programming crowd, they wouldn't have done so.

Comment: @Kris-I: An example of what? I've given you the code you need, haven't I?